# Rust the type of this value must be known in this context

Tags: rust

I'm having a problem fixing the following error in Rust:

```
error[E0619]: the type of this value must be known in this context
  --> src\factory\mod.rs:35:7
   |
35 |       bot.add_new_instruction(transfer_instruction);
   |       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**factory/mod.rs**:

```
mod bot;
use self::bot::*;

pub struct Factory {
    bots: Vec<Bot>,
}

impl Factory {
    pub fn new() -> Factory {
        Factory { bots: Vec::new() }
    }

    pub fn interpret_instruction(&mut self) {
        let low_chip_transfer_target = ChipTransferTarget::Bot(5);
        let high_chip_transfer_target = ChipTransferTarget::Bot(1);
        let from_bot = 2;

        let transfer_instruction =
            ChipTransferInstruction::new(low_chip_transfer_target, high_chip_transfer_target);
        let bot = self.bots[from_bot];

        // Erroneous line below
        bot.add_new_instruction(transfer_instruction);
    }
}
```

**factory/bot.rs**:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum ChipTransferTarget {
    Output(usize),
    Bot(usize),
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ChipTransferInstruction {
    pub low_value_target: ChipTransferTarget,
    pub high_value_target: ChipTransferTarget,
}

impl ChipTransferInstruction {
    pub fn new(
        low_value_target: ChipTransferTarget,
        high_value_target: ChipTransferTarget,
    ) -> ChipTransferInstruction {
        ChipTransferInstruction {
            low_value_target,
            high_value_target,
        }
    }
}

pub struct Bot {
    id: usize,
    transfer_instructions: Vec<ChipTransferInstruction>,
}

impl Bot {
    pub fn new(id: usize) -> Bot {
        Bot {
            id,
            transfer_instructions: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn add_new_instruction(&mut self, instruction: ChipTransferInstruction) {
        self.transfer_instructions.push(instruction);
    }
}
```

I've removed the code that is irrelevant to this error, as there is more logic.

I have tried annotating `bot` and `transfer_instruction` in the `interpret_instruction` method, but I still get the same error and I'm not sure that is wrong.

I've researched this error message and most of the problems are regarding vectors and streams that are not annotated, but from what I can tell the compiler is able to infer the type of every variable here.

Comment: You have removed too much. When [pasted into the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2bc4bcfc9a6db28a94c48667e3eddc68&version=stable), compiling your code doesn't cause the error message you report. To get it to compile, I just needed to follow the compiler's instructions and change `let bot = self.bots[from_bot]` to `let bot = &mut self.bots[from_bot]`.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix it thanks to [user4815162342](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600898/user4815162342)'s comment.

I removed too much. In my code I previously had:

```
for capture in move_chips_regex.captures_iter(input) {
    let from_bot = capture[1].parse().unwrap();
```

where `move_chips_regex` was a regular expression.

The fix was annotating `from_bot` as `usize`, like so:

```
let from_bot: usize = capture[1].parse().unwrap();
```